# ec2 ssh operation timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

```
$ ssh -vvv -i "AMSKeyPair.pem" ec2-user@ec2-52-43-0-65.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

> OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0 debug1: Reading configuration data
>
> /etc/ssh/ssh_config debug2: resolving
>
> "ec2-52-43-0-65.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com" port 22 debug2:
>
> ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0 debug1: Connecting to
>
> ec2-52-43-0-65.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [52.43.0.65] port 22.
>
> debug1: connect to address 52.43.0.65 port 22: Operation timed out
>
> ssh: connect to host ec2-52-43-0-65.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
>
> port 22: Operation timed out

Corresponding Security Group allos all inbound traffic on all ports.
[image]

I tried on different internet connections, so I don't think NAT is there.

PS: I am not a first time ec2 user, used it before.

Comment: Are you connecting from an EC2 instance? Your security group only allows connections from systems in the same security group. Is this what you intended?

Comment: Nope I wasn't . I see. changed to 0.0.0.0/0 and now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

[image]Changed Security Group's source from sg-57710f2a to 0.0.0.0/0
Now it works. As @john-hanley pointed out sg-57710f2a allows only connection from within host under that Security Group not outside

Comment: Thanks, changing the source to 0.0.0.0/0 in in-bound rules solved the error for me.

Comment: Is this safe to allow all IP addresses?